# Rubberband with iScroll and jQuery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, iscroll

The headline says it all. At start of my app I retrieve data from a php file (some divs) and append them to an wrapper-div. Around this wrapper-div (not called wrapper) is the iScroll wrapper.

iScroll is working, but there is a rubberband effect.

Here's the (index) HTML:

```
<div data-role="header" data-theme="c" data-position="fixed">
          <h1>Title</h1>
      </div><!-- /header -->

      <div id="wrapper">
          <div id="scroller">

      <div data-role="content" id="content">

         <div id="headlinesindex">


          <div class="span3" id="9999999999"></div>

        </div>
        </div>
       </div>

      </div>

      <script>
          $(document).ready(function() {
                            onBodyLoad();
                            });
          </script>
```

And here's the javascript-file:

```
    function onBodyLoad()
{
    $.ajax({
    url: "headlines_getter.php?last="+ $(".span3:last").attr('id') ,
    success: function(html) {
           if(html){    
            $("#headlinesindex").append(html);

           setTimeout(function () {
                      myScroll.refresh();
                      }, 0);

        }
    }
    });
}

function onDeviceReady()
{        
    var myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
}
```

I've played arround with the `setTimeout` as it is explained at iscroll.com, but it changes nothing... Hope you know what's wrong.

Thanks in advance. Best regards, John.

Comment: I used iScroll4 with JQM 1.3.1 and used the solution provided above by [JDEV](http://stackoverflow.com/users/929973/jdev) on the pageshow event to make it work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same issue.

It came from the outer "wrapper" not being sized correctly in iscroll.

If it is sized the same size as the inner "scroller" height then the iscroll will have no where to go and rubber band.

I fixed it for me, and created a fork for others with the same issue:

https://github.com/meckdahl/iscroll

================================== Advanced Usage

Here is some addon functions I use to maintain my 20+ scroll containers in our Spine.JS mobile app:

For each page I set a specific wrapper like such:

```
<div id="wrapper2">
```

Then I dynamically create iScroll only if that page is loaded:

After the content for the page is loaded I call like such:

```
window.resetScroll(2)
window.setScrolling(true)
```

This will re-initialize iScroll for this page.

Here are the functions I define on my root page:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   // maximum wrapper index = 23 currently (9/12/12)
    var myScrolls = [];
    myScrolls.length = 29; // Scrolls to look for wrapper1-30

    var refreshScrolling = function() {
        //console.log('refreshScrolling Active Scroll Items: ');
        myScrolls.forEach( function(scrollItem){
            scrollItem.refresh();
        });
    };

   var refreshScroll = function(wrapperNumber) {
       //console.log('refreshScroll wrapperNumber: wrapper' + wrapperNumber.toString());

       var i = wrapperNumber;
       setTimeout(function () {
        (myScrolls[i-1]).refresh();
       }, 100);
   };

   // This looks for and initializes and dynamic scrolls that Spine recently put in memory
   // and have not been initialized yet.
    var setScrolling = function() {

       for (var i=1; i < myScrolls.length+1; i++){

           if (($("#wrapper"+(i).toString()).length !== 0)  ){

               if((myScrolls[i-1] !== null) && (myScrolls[i-1] !== undefined)){
                   // Already setup
               }
               else{
                   myScrolls[i-1] = new iScroll('wrapper'+ (i).toString(),
                           { hScroll: false, hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false });
 created.");
               }
           }
       }
    }

    // This must be called on a view with dynamic content to re-create the view to fit the potentially
    // changing content size.  It will only rebuild the one scroll whose index is passed in.
    // The index should be the wrapper# for the view attached to the controller.
    // Call setScrolling after this to catch any uninitialized views.
    var resetScroll = function(wrapperNumber) {


       var i = wrapperNumber;
       //   if (!(i in myScrolls)) continue; // skip nonexistent elements && !(myScrolls[i-1] )
       if (($("#wrapper"+(i).toString()).length !== 0)  ){

           if( (myScrolls[i-1] !== null) && (myScrolls[i-1] !== undefined)){
               // Destroy Skipped right now
               myScrolls[i-1].destroy();
               myScrolls[i-1] = null;
           }

           myScrolls[i-1] = new iScroll('wrapper'+ (i).toString(),
                   { hScroll: false, hScrollbar: false, vScrollbar: false });
           created.");
       }
    }

    function loaded() {
        setTimeout(function () {
            setScrolling();
        }, 100);
    }
    window.addEventListener('load', loaded, false);

</script>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. i didn't tested it because i threw iscroll out of my project, but i will implement it in future updates, and than i will use your method! thanks

Comment: Awesome, thanks. I too was puzzled, and figured it was some problem with the way it was calculating the height, but didn't exactly know where.

Comment: for me, I made the changes using the fork that u have pointed.. but still having the problem. any idea? I used the lasted iscroll4.

Comment: I use this in an web application that has 30 or so independent pages with scroll, that are loaded dynamically.  All that to say I determine page load for any page and create and re-initialize the iScroll dymnamically once it is loaded.  When new content is added (sometimes) it does not update right and iScroll will need a refresh.  I tend to create the iScroll after the content is loaded so I do not see this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with my custom script so I changed the code and now it's working nicely:

```
var myScroll;

function loaded() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        myScroll = new iScroll('wrapper');
        myScroll.refresh();       
    } , 100 );
}
```

And I call it on "onDeviceReady":

```
function onDeviceReady()
{        
    loaded();
}
```

Comment: thanks, but this changes nothing. rubberband-effect is always there. i retrieve like 48 divs (wrapped into the headlinesindex-div), maybe it's too much for iScroll? but this seems not logic..

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Eccgy/

Check this may be help you

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple iscroller that would help .
its very easy to implement

include scripts and jsut add an attribute data-iscroll to the div, which you need the effect.

https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview